# Spring Ehcache works only if method called in same request

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data, ehcache

I am trying to cache my results, but every call to the page (refresh) hits the db. Any help appreciated, thanks.

**Controller**

```
showPage(){
    MyPage<PhoneInfo> myPage = (MyPage<PhoneInfo>) phoneInfoService.findAllByOption(options, new MyPage<PhoneInfo>(page.intValue(), size.intValue()));
    //further experiment.. below does not hit db
    myPage = (MyPage<PhoneInfo>) phoneInfoService.findAllByOption(options, new MyPage<PhoneInfo>(page.intValue(), size.intValue()));
}
```

The 2nd call to the service method does not make db call, which is correct.
However a page refresh calls the showPage() again and the 1st call to service hits db again. I want it to come from cache.

I tested with 2 unit tests, both tests had same call to the service method, Test 1 hits db while Test 2 skips, which is correct. Multiple service calls within a test also skipped, which is again correct.

**Specs**

> Spring 4.3.3.RELEASE, Security 4.2.3.RELEASE, Hibernate 5.2.8.Final,
>   Ehcache 2.10.4

**CacheConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CachingConfig {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager cacheManager) {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(cacheManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheCacheManager() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cmfb = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        cmfb.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
        cmfb.setShared(true);
        return cmfb;
    }
}
```

**src/resources/ehcache.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"     updateCheck="true"  monitoring="autodetect"     dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />

    <cache name="myPageCache"       maxEntriesLocalHeap="1000"      maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000"         eternal="false"         diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"      timeToIdleSeconds="86400" timeToLiveSeconds="86400"         overflowToDisk="false"      memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"         transactionalMode="off">        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />    </cache>

</ehcache>
```

**Update 1**
Listing service methods below

```
Cacheable(value = "myPageCache", key = "{#options, #pageable}")
public MyPage<PhoneInfo>findAllByOption(PhoneOption options, MyPage<PhoneInfo> pageable){
    MyPage<PhoneInfo> myPage = phoneInfoRepoImpl.findAll(options, pageable);
    myPage.setTotalRows(_phoneInfoService.getCount(options, pageable));
    return myPage;
}

@Cacheable(value = "myPageCache", key = "#options")
public int getCount(PhoneOption options, MyPage<PhoneInfo> pageable){
    return phoneInfoRepoImpl.getCount(options, pageable);
}
```

**Update 2**
Unit tests

```
@Test
public void test1(){
    PhoneOption options = new PhoneOption();
    options.setName("239");
    options.setStatus('1');
    MyPage<PhoneInfo> myPage = phoneInfoService.findAllByOption(options, new MyPage<PhoneInfo>()); //hits db, Ok
    myPage = phoneInfoService.findAllByOption(options, new MyPage<PhoneInfo>()); //skips db, OK
    myPage = phoneInfoService.findAllByOption(options, new MyPage<PhoneInfo>(2, 20)); //hits db, OK as MyPage changed
}

@Test
public void test2(){
    PhoneOption options = new PhoneOption();
    options.setName("239");
    options.setStatus('1');
    MyPage<PhoneInfo> myPage = phoneInfoService.findAllByOption(options, new MyPage<PhoneInfo>()); //these options exactly same as Test1, skips db, OK!
    myPage = phoneInfoService.findAllByOption(options, new MyPage<PhoneInfo>()); //skips db, Ok
    myPage = phoneInfoService.findAllByOption(options, new MyPage<PhoneInfo>(2, 20)); //skips db, Ok
}
```

**Update 3**Implemented hashCode and equals in all tested objects

Now in unit tests it hits db all the time! So behavior is worsened.
hashcode is same for equal/same objects, equals working properly as well, returning true for objects with similar properties.

Comment: Assuming that you have placed @Cacheable annotation on the findAllByOption method, Then whether it picks from cache or not depends on the arguments that you are passing. If they are same for every page refresh surely you would be getting it from the cache. Also, your cache time to live is 86400ms. What is the frequency of your page refresh call?

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, yes I have Cacheable on the method. Exact same arguments are being passed during refresh, same for every page refresh, not getting from cache. For testing, I am refreshing the page within seconds.. will post service methods too

Comment: I see, Eventhough you might have had the same values in options object but since it is always a new object with different hashkey, It won't work like you expect. you need to have a different key generating strategy.

Comment: you can try a key something like #options.field1 + #options.field2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key `"{#options, #pageable}"` will have new value each and every time even if you pass the same set of values in those objects as they are completely new objects after every page refresh. Hence they are getting cached every time in the first call. To avoid that you need to change the key.Try making use of fields inside your object like `#object.field`.

Comment: My Options is a class with numerous fields such as id, type, List etc., any or all can be null. How can I generate a key in such a case? Tried #options.id + #options.code but both are null, throwing error _The operator 'ADD' is not supported between objects of type 'null' and 'null'_

Comment: Would it make sense to mix all fields in _Options.hashCode()_ ? Would that work? Would I then be able to use #options as key in service method?

Comment: Ideally, you should not be caching your results if that is the case as there can be multiple combinations but if you have a fixed mandatory set of fields use them to form a key.

Comment: Yes Options are actually bunch of search options, so results can be very varied; app is flexible & robust, just slow with many users, thought caching would be very beneficial. The mandatory set of fields would need to be unique as it is the key right? Any better alternatives for my scenario?

Comment: Why I said you should not cache in your scenario because as there are multiple combinations, for every combination your output will be cached and cache size might reach it's limit very easily. As you are saying it is related to search, Elasticsearch might be the best fit.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for all your help & time, appreciate it. Will try to do hashCode() and look into Elasticsearch.

Comment: Still finding it strange.. I had 2 unit tests, both created Options with similar fields yet cache works.. according to you the hashcode should be different, so how is cache working fine then?

Comment: When you simply use #options, I am not sure whether it uses hashkey or tostring or someother constraint...but if you are passing same object to the two tests, then it's an expected behaviour..

Comment: The objects are constructed each within the 2 tests, same object not being passed to them. I do have an elaborate Option.toString(), shall post the unit tests too..

Comment: Check the keys that got stored in ehcache...you will get to some conclusion then.

Comment: Accepting @Rakesh as I tried with a very simple object with hashCode() and it caches fine; must have messed up the hashCode and equals in my complex class.

Comment: Finally got it to work, seems like a quirk - the #pageable is my 2nd key in @Cacheable, was getting hashcode out of pageNumber & pageSize, same hashcode returned but not caching. I used #pageable.pageNumber, #pageable.pageSize as 2nd & 3rd key and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

The elements that make up the key need to have the proper `equals` and `hashcode` defined, so that even though you end up with different instances, values that are equal will cause the right cache hit.

Comment: Implemented equals & hascode, behaviour is worse, always hitting  cache.. Putting in Update 3

Comment: Cleaned up hashcode and equals and it helped move me to the right direction, so thanks.